# Tabs in iWork-style Inspector panel

Tags: cocoa, tabs, styling, nspanel

how does one get the look of the tab buttons as they appear in iWork '09 Inspector `NSPanel`?

Closest I could get is `NSSegmentedControl` with "Small Square" style. Unfortunately, at least under Snow Leopard that results in grayed selection instead of blue selection.

Any ideas what Apple did to get the bluish aqua-style selection in various iWork '09 Inspector `NSPanel`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top icon bar is a Radio Group, which is actually a NSMatrix filled with NSButtonCells. You can check this using the application UIElementInspector.app, which is a sample code provided with XCode.

The selected cell displays its alternate image, other cells display their image.

Comment: This is the way I went about doing this half a year ago: a matrix with button cells that, upon click, changes the active tab in a tab view. I don't use alternate images, but I would if I needed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The iWork inspector tab buttons use images for their appearance. You can see the images if you **Show Package Contents** on one of the app packages and have a look in the `Resources` folder.

To replicate this you could use an `NSSegmentedControl` with a custom `NSSegmentedCell` subclass that draws the images.

Comment: Shocking as it is, you're right. It's really odd that they don't provide a standard way to paint this segmented control.